# Nested loops for date into single array

Tags: arrays, date, for-loop, nested

say for example I need to generate dates within a given range of years into 3 arrays. One for days, one for months and another for years. Keeping it simple for now, so assuming that all months had 31 days in them. How do I come out with the 3 arrays such that each corresponding element of the arrays match with each other. For example:

```
const int n = 1000;
int dayarray[n];
int montharray[n];
int yeararray[n];

for (int k = 2016; k < 2018; k++) {        // for loop for years 2016 to 2017
    for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++) {         // for loop for month
        for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++) {     // for loop for day
            dayarray[??] = i;
            montharray[??] = j;
            yeararray[??] = k;
        }
    }
}
```

What do i need to put in ?? of the arrays such that dayarray[1] = 1, montharray[1] = 1, yeararray[1] = 2016 .....dayarray[32] = 1, montharray[32] = 2, yeararray[32] = 2016  .....dayarray[373] = 1, montharray[373] = 1, yeararray[373] = 2017

Also, I have to do this for 300 years, and I think i read somewhere that if there could be an error if the array is too large. Is there also a better way of doing this other than brute force? Hope I've explained my problem clearly. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you wish to make the day array larger than 31 and the month array larger than 12? Since you know the values loop there is no need to store that much data

Comment: Hi, because in the exercise, I need to generate all possible dates from 1st jan 1900 to 31st dec 2199 and compare it to something else. So I would need to store these days, months and years in 3 separate arrays. But yea, i'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing it. Do you have any suggestions?